# How to hide names from the main contact list?

Tags: android

I am trying to write an app that hides some names from the contact list when it is enabled (for example, hide the names that starts with 'A').

I was able to write my own simple contact list with this function and set it as my main contact list, but it would be a hard work to implement all the original contact list functionalities in my app.

So I am wondering if it is possible to call the original contact list but with a custom filter or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start the contact picker with an intent without writing your own contact displayer, there currently is no way to do this.